# Hbase filter a column with list of values

Tags: java, scala, hbase

How can i pass a list of values to a SingleColumnFilter for an hbase scan and query ?

```
val ListOfID = List("ID1","ID2",...,"ID15",...,"ID150")
```

I know how to filter for one value :

```
val IDFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("header"), Bytes.toBytes("ID"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(ID)))
```

But i would like to pass a list of value to the filter, because my list has more than 150 elements.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution i found, with RegexStringComparator
it works, but i don't know if its the best that can be done :

```
val ListOfID = List("ID1","ID2",...,"ID15",...,"ID150") 
val IDListString = ListOfID.mkString("|")

val scan = new Scan


val IDFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("header"), Bytes.toBytes("networkIdentifier"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new RegexStringComparator(IDListString))

val filters = new FilterList(IDFilter)    
scan.setFilter(filters)
```